# Trying to display graph showing in x axis dates

Tags: matplotlib

I am quite newbie into matplotlib and I am struggling to plot a line graph because of my x axis.

I have 3 lists:

```
x=[01-01-2018,02-01-2018,03-01-2018]
y1=[10,12,9]
y2=[7,9,1]
```

I am looking forward to plot a 2 line graph setting in the x axis the dates:

I am looking forward to do this using subplots in order to customize the graphs as I like.

In order to do this what I tried was:

```
ax1=plt.subplot2grid((1,1),(0,0))
ax1.plot(x,y1,label='test1')
ax1.plot(x,y2,label='test2')

plt.show()
```

However it outputs:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '01-01-2018'
```

I would like an output the 2 line graph and in the x axis the dates.
How can I display the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify the `xticks` directly. Here is an example that works:

```
y1 = [10, 12, 9]
y2 = [7, 9, 1]
x=['01-01-2018','02-01-2018','03-01-2018']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(y1,label='test1')
ax.plot(y2, label='test2')
ax.set_xticks([0,1,2])
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
plt.show()
```

The line `ax.set_xticks` sets the specific ticks that will appear on the `x axis` for each point -- `0` is the tick for the first data point, `1` for the second etc.

`ax.set_xticklabels` takes a list of strings that must be equal in length to how many ticks you made. It then pairs each label to each tick.

You should also checkout the [matplotlib documentation and examples](https://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html).